# SwapChain pointer was nullptr exception DIRECTX 11

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

So i'm a total noob with DirectX, never done anything with it. I studied some already written framework and also read the piece of the Frank Luna book (Game Programming with DirectX) about making a framework. I'm not good with WINAPI too, but i think that's not the problem here. When i run the code i get this exception:
**this->m_swapChain was nullptr**
How can i solve this? I tried not initializing m_swapChain to NULL but nothing changed.
This is the DirectClass.h file

```
#pragma comment(lib, "dxgi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "d3dcompiler.lib")

#include <d3d11.h>
#include <directxmath.h>
using namespace DirectX;

class DirectClass {
public:
    DirectClass();
    ~DirectClass();
    ID3D11Device *GetDevice() { return m_device; };
    ID3D11DeviceContext *GetDeviceContext() { return m_deviceContext; };
    IDXGISwapChain*GetSwapChain() { return m_swapChain; };
    HRESULT Initialize(HWND hwnd);
private:

    ID3D11Device *m_device;
    ID3D11DeviceContext *m_deviceContext;

    IDXGISwapChain *m_swapChain;
    DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC m_swapChainDesc;

    ID3D11Texture2D *m_backBuffer;                  //Back Buffer
    ID3D11Texture2D *m_depthStencilBuffer;          //Depth Stencil Buffer

    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC m_depthBufferDesc;         //Depth Buffer Desc
    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC m_depthStencilDesc;    
    ID3D11DepthStencilView *m_depthStencilView;

    D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC m_depthStencilViewDesc;   
    D3D11_VIEWPORT m_viewPort;  


    ID3D11DepthStencilState* m_depthStencilState;
    ID3D11RenderTargetView *m_renderTargetView;
    
    int m_screenHeight;
    int m_screenWidth;

    bool m_windowed;
    //render target
    //render target view

};
```

This is the DirectClass.cpp file

```
#include "DirectClass.h"

DirectClass::DirectClass() {
    m_windowed = false;
}
DirectClass::~DirectClass() {

}
HRESULT DirectClass::Initialize(HWND hwnd) {
    HRESULT hr=S_OK;
    m_windowed = true;
    m_screenHeight= GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);
    m_screenWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);


    //feature levels
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[]{
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_2,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_9_3,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
        D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    };
    //swap chain
    if (m_windowed) {
        m_swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = 600;
        m_swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = 800;
        m_swapChainDesc.Windowed = true;
    }
    else {
        m_swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Height = m_screenHeight;
        m_swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Width = m_screenWidth;
        m_swapChainDesc.Windowed = false;
    }

    m_swapChainDesc.BufferCount = 2;
    m_swapChainDesc.OutputWindow = hwnd; // dopo correggi
    m_swapChainDesc.Flags = 0;
    m_swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    m_swapChainDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    m_swapChainDesc.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_DISCARD_ON_PRESENT;
    m_swapChainDesc.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
    
    hr=D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(nullptr, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 0, 0, 0, ARRAYSIZE(featureLevels), D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
                                    &m_swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, featureLevels, &m_deviceContext );   //The problem is here. I get an exception like this "this->m_swapChain was nullptr

    m_swapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*)&m_backBuffer);
    m_backBuffer->Release();
    //Descrizione del depth buffer
    ZeroMemory(&m_depthBufferDesc, sizeof(m_depthBufferDesc));
    if (m_windowed) {
        m_depthBufferDesc.Width = 800;
        m_depthBufferDesc.Height = 600;
    }
    else {
        m_depthBufferDesc.Width = m_screenWidth;
        m_depthBufferDesc.Height = m_screenHeight;
    }
    
    m_depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    m_depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    m_depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;  
    m_depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    m_depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
    m_depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;              
    m_depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;     
    m_depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = 0;
    m_depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;

    m_depthStencilDesc.DepthEnable = true;
    m_depthStencilDesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL; 
    m_depthStencilDesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;  

    m_depthStencilDesc.StencilEnable = true;
    m_depthStencilDesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
    m_depthStencilDesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
    
    
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
    m_depthStencilDesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
    
    m_device->CreateTexture2D(&m_depthBufferDesc, 0, &m_depthStencilBuffer); 
    m_device->CreateDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilBuffer, 0, &m_depthStencilView);

    if (m_windowed) {
        m_viewPort.Height = 600;
        m_viewPort.Width = 800;
    }
    else {
        m_viewPort.Height = m_screenHeight;
        m_viewPort.Width = m_screenWidth;
    }
    m_viewPort.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
    m_viewPort.MinDepth = 0.0f;
    m_viewPort.TopLeftX = 0.0f;
    m_viewPort.TopLeftY = 0.0f;

    m_device->CreateRenderTargetView(m_backBuffer, 0, &m_renderTargetView);


    m_deviceContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &m_renderTargetView, m_depthStencilView);
    m_deviceContext->RSSetViewports(1, &m_viewPort);
    
    
    return hr;
}
```

There are probably more errors than the one im asking about (if you find something not done good or missing tell me, no problems) in the code but i did this by myself and by looking online to some example (copying something too, but uderstanding the majority of it)

This is the MainClass.h file (copied from here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn643742(v=vs.85).aspx )

```
#pragma once
#include "DirectClass.h"
#include<Windows.h>
#include <string>
class MainClass
{
public:
    MainClass();
    ~MainClass();

    HRESULT CreateDesktopWindow();

    HWND GetWindowHandle() { return m_hWnd; };

    static LRESULT CALLBACK StaticWindowProc(
        HWND hWnd,
        UINT uMsg,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam
    );

    HRESULT Present(IDXGISwapChain *swapChain);

private:
    HMENU     m_hMenu;
    RECT      m_rc;
    HWND      m_hWnd;
};

static HINSTANCE m_hInstance;
static std::wstring m_windowClassName;
```

And the MainClass.cpp file, this has no error im pretty sure

## include "MainClass.h"

```
MainClass::MainClass()
{
    m_windowClassName = L"Direct3DWindowClass";
    m_hInstance = NULL;
}
MainClass::~MainClass(){}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Create a window for our Direct3D viewport.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
HRESULT MainClass::CreateDesktopWindow()
{
    // Window resources are dealt with here.
    HRESULT hr=S_OK;
    if (m_hInstance == NULL)
        m_hInstance = (HINSTANCE)GetModuleHandle(NULL);

    HICON hIcon = NULL;
    WCHAR szExePath[MAX_PATH];
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, szExePath, MAX_PATH);

    // If the icon is NULL, then use the first one found in the exe
    if (hIcon == NULL)
        hIcon = ExtractIcon(m_hInstance, szExePath, 0);

    // Register the windows class
    WNDCLASS wndClass;
    wndClass.style = CS_DBLCLKS;
    wndClass.lpfnWndProc = MainClass::StaticWindowProc;
    wndClass.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wndClass.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wndClass.hInstance = m_hInstance;
    wndClass.hIcon = hIcon;
    wndClass.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wndClass.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)GetStockObject(BLACK_BRUSH);
    wndClass.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    wndClass.lpszClassName = m_windowClassName.c_str();

    if (!RegisterClass(&wndClass))
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        if (dwError != ERROR_CLASS_ALREADY_EXISTS)
            return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }

    m_rc;
    int x = CW_USEDEFAULT;
    int y = CW_USEDEFAULT;

    // No menu in this example.
    m_hMenu = NULL;

    // This example uses a non-resizable 640 by 480 viewport for simplicity.
    int nDefaultWidth = 800;
    int nDefaultHeight = 600;
    SetRect(&m_rc, 0, 0, nDefaultWidth, nDefaultHeight);
    AdjustWindowRect(
        &m_rc,
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        (m_hMenu != NULL) ? true : false
    );

    // Create the window for our viewport.
    m_hWnd = CreateWindow(
        m_windowClassName.c_str(),
        L"Cube11",
        WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        x, y,
        (m_rc.right - m_rc.left), (m_rc.bottom - m_rc.top),
        0,
        m_hMenu,
        m_hInstance,
        0
    );

    if (m_hWnd == NULL)
    {
        DWORD dwError = GetLastError();
        return HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(dwError);
    }

    return hr;
}
HRESULT MainClass::Present(IDXGISwapChain *swapChain) {
    HRESULT hr;
    hr = S_OK;
    swapChain->Present(1, 0);
    return hr;
}

LRESULT CALLBACK MainClass::StaticWindowProc(
    HWND hWnd,
    UINT uMsg,
    WPARAM wParam,
    LPARAM lParam
)
{
    switch (uMsg)
    {
    case WM_CLOSE:
    {
        HMENU hMenu;
        hMenu = GetMenu(hWnd);
        if (hMenu != NULL)
        {
            DestroyMenu(hMenu);
        }
        DestroyWindow(hWnd);
        UnregisterClass(
            m_windowClassName.c_str(),
            m_hInstance
        );
        return 0;
    }

    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

And the main

```
#include "DirectClass.h"
#include "MainClass.h"

#include <memory>

INT WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE, HINSTANCE, LPSTR, int)
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;

    // Enable run-time memory check for debug builds.
#if defined(DEBUG) | defined(_DEBUG)
    _CrtSetDbgFlag(_CRTDBG_ALLOC_MEM_DF | _CRTDBG_LEAK_CHECK_DF);
#endif
    std::shared_ptr<MainClass> winMain = std::shared_ptr<MainClass>(new MainClass());
    // Create a window.
    hr = winMain->CreateDesktopWindow();

    std::shared_ptr<DirectClass> directClass = std::shared_ptr<DirectClass>(new DirectClass());

    HWND hwnd = winMain->GetWindowHandle();
    directClass->Initialize(hwnd);

    IDXGISwapChain *sC = directClass->GetSwapChain();

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        winMain->Present(sC);
    }
}
```

Sorry if this is bad written, stupid, nonsense and bad optimized.
Maybe by solving that exception i can try to improve this code, thanks.

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used DX11, but if the swapchain isn't initialized, then the call failed. Try to look at the debug output for the relevant error code, and try to solve the problem.

Comment: Rakete1111 i can't initialize a IDXGISwapChain struct, i can only ude the DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC struct to describe it and than use the createDeviceAndSwapChain function.

Comment: In `DirectClass.cpp` you call `m_backBuffer->Release();`, I don't think you want that. You're releasing the texture that your swapchain is actually using, which is considered a "bad thing" :-)

Comment: – cehnehdeh i tried removing the Release but i still have the error. I also tried to separate the creation of the swap chain and the device and i have also moved all the variables inside the Initialize method but still getting that error

Comment: Ok i found the error. I needed to ZeroMemory() the swap chain desc and to set numerator=60 and denominator=1, that solved everything, now i have another problem but i can solve it (there is no window popping up)